# What will this C expression return in type?(int/double)

Tags: c

Hi I would like to ask the result of an expression,

```
int x = 7;
double y = 2;
```

what will the type be when (x / y + 2)?

is it a double, long, int, string or byte?
thanks

Comment: there is no string or byte type in c :)

Comment: if c++, you might use `decltype` to have that information.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358864/operations-with-different-int-types

Comment: `is it a double, long, int, string or byte?` -- perfect example for no effort shown!!

Comment: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

Comment: @Andi Perkaa Use `float` or 'double' to take result.

Answer (score 4):

It's a `double`. The *arithmetic conversion* rules come in to play when you have an expression containing mixed types:

`x` is converted to a `double` in the evaluation of `x / y`, and 2 is converted to a `double` when added to that term.

Note that this is true regardless of the range of `int` (and `double`) on your platform.

Answer (score 2):

It returns `double` type.

In  `(x / y + 2)` first `x/y` performed and here variable `x` is of `int` type and `y` is of `double` type, so you are performing division operator between two different type, hence  **arithmetic type conversation** happens i.e temporarily `int` gets converted or promoted to `double` i.e `x/y` yields in `double` type.

And next  `(x/y)(double)` + 2`(int)` again yields in `double`.

Comment: I'd avoid implying an *order* of evaluation, using the term *grouping* is preferable: the type of 2 + x / y is also a `double`.

Comment: It is not "implicit typecasting" but [arithmetic conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8). The word *cast* in C means the thing that is explicit, i.e. `(type)expression` .

Answer (score 0):

The resulting type of the expression will be `double`.  This is detailed in section 6.3.1.8 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) which details the **Usual arithmetic conversions**:

> First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `long double`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `long double`.
>
> **Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `double`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `double`.**
>
> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `float`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `float`.
>
> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands.

The paragraph in bold states that if one operand is a `double` and the other has an integer type, both operands will have type `double`.  This is the case in your expression.

Since `x` has type `double` and `y` has type `int`, the value of `y` is converted to `double` and the full expression `x / y` has type `double`.  From there, `x / y` has type double and `2` has type `int`, the value `2` is converted to `double` and so `x / y + 2` has type `double`.